# How to get data from a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a following code:

```
<div class="match">
  <div class="match-name">MATCH 1</div>
  <div class="match-league">LEAGUE 2</div>
</div>

<div class="match">
  <div class="match-name">MATCH 2</div>
  <div class="match-league">LEAGUE 1</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to scrape the data and the output should be an array of objects using this data-model:

```
{
  name: "match-name"
  league: "match-league"
}
```

I am not sure about the scraping part. How to loop through the divs and get the values?

Comment: Have you tried with: var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".match");

Comment: yes, dont know how to extract name and league for match then tho :-( @Loki

Comment: are you looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: This is basic JavaScript. Selecting elements and reading their text or HTML.

Comment: If you still need this here is the https://jsfiddle.net/a7f5L0bc/22/ with sample solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) after converting the result of [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to an `Array` using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and `map` each `.match` to an object of the desired format:

```js
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('.match');

var arr = Array.from(matches).map(m => {
  let name = m.querySelector('.match-name').innerText,
      league = m.querySelector('.match-league').innerText;
      return {name : name, league : league}
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="match-name">MATCH 1</div>
  <div class="match-league">LEAGUE 2</div>
</div>

<div class="match">
  <div class="match-name">MATCH 2</div>
  <div class="match-league">LEAGUE 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `querySelector` API

```js
const matches = document.querySelectorAll(".match")

console.log([...matches].map(match => ({
  name: match.querySelector(".match-name").innerText,
  league: match.querySelector(".match-league").innerText
})))
```

```html
<div class="match">
  <div class="match-name">MATCH 1</div>
  <div class="match-league">LEAGUE 2</div>
</div>

<div class="match">
  <div class="match-name">MATCH 2</div>
  <div class="match-league">LEAGUE 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants. Also, we tend not to answer questions where the OP hasn't even made an attempt at a solution. It just attracts more poor questions.